# ClassNotFoundException when trying Speech Recogniton in Java

Tags: java, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  try {
            URL url;
            if (args.length > 0) {
                url = new File(args[0]).toURI().toURL();
            } else {
                url = HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml");
            }

            System.out.println("Loading...");

            ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(url);
            System.out.println("Configured Successfully");
        Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer"); // I found exception in this line
        System.out.println("Recognizer Ready");
        Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");
        System.out.println("Microphone Ready");

            /* allocate the resource necessary for the recognizer */
            recognizer.allocate();

            /* the microphone will keep recording until the program exits */
        if (microphone.startRecording()) {

        System.out.println("Say: (Good morning | Hello) " +
                     "( Bhiksha | Evandro | Paul | Philip | Rita | Will )");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println          ("Start speaking. Press Ctrl-C to quit.\n");

                    /*
                     * This method will return when the end of speech
                     * is reached. Note that the endpointer will determine
                     * the end of speech.
                     */ 
            Result result = recognizer.recognize();

            if (result != null) {           String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();            System.out.println("You
said: " + resultText + "\n");
            } else {            System.out.println("I can't hear what you said.\n");
            }       }
        } else {        System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");         recognizer.deallocate();        System.exit(1);
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem when loading HelloWorld: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (PropertyException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem configuring HelloWorld: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Problem creating HelloWorld: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } }
```

With this code I got the following exception:

```
class not found !java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 edu.cmu.sphinx.model.acoustic.WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.Model
 Problem configuring HelloWorld: Property Exception component:'flatLinguist'
 property:'acousticModel' - mandatory property is not set!
 edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.InternalConfigurationException
 Property Exception component:'flatLinguist' property:'acousticModel' - mandatory
 property is not set!
 edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.InternalConfigurationException
```

This error occurs when I run my program.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think you should add more detail to your question. Like relevant parts of code. Where is catch this exception?

Comment: Format your code properly using the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: What does the file `helloworld.config.xml` contain?

Comment: what I do? please Suggest me

Comment: It contains configuration Information  <component name="recognizer" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer">
        <property name="decoder" value="decoder"/>
        <propertylist name="monitors">
            <item>accuracyTracker </item>
            <item>speedTracker </item>
            <item>memoryTracker </item>
        </propertylist>
    </component>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log it looks like you are using outdated config.xml file referring to the class edu.cmu.sphinx.model.acoustic.WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.Model

This class was removed from Sphinx4 long time ago

Download latest sphinx4 sources and use demos from the latest Sphinx4 including config files and everything will work fine.